# Firebase cloud function object update creating recursion

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

My application has a simple cloud function to keep track of created/updated timestamps.  It looks like this:

```
export const objectChanges = functions
  .firestore
  .document('objects/{id}')
  .onWrite(event => {
    const patch: {created_at?: string, updated_at: string} = {
      updated_at: <string> event.timestamp
    };

    if (!event.data.previous) {
      patch.created_at = event.timestamp;
    }

    return event.data.ref.set(patch, {merge: true});
  });
```

As soon as I upload this function and create/modify an object in the list, it starts constantly ticking the updated_at.  I'm guessing it's detecting the change it itself is making to the updated_at field.  This behavior confuses me, considering the documentation shows an example of this kind of update.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#writing_data

Is there a nuance I'm missing, or is this a Firestore bug?

Comment: Looks like you're probably missing this part: *"Note: Any time you write to the same document that triggered a function, you are at risk of creating an infinite loop. **Use caution and ensure that you safely exit the function when no change is needed**."* It doesn't appear as though any of the examples demonstrate this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the example given in the docs there is one condition that is checked to see if `name` is changed. If yes then only execute the following code. If its unchanged, it simply `return`s, like this:

```
// We'll only update if the name has changed.
// This is crucial to prevent infinite loops.
if (data.name == previousData.name) return;
```

So in your case also, you will need to check if the actual data of your object (all the fields except `updated_at`) is changed or not. If nothing else (apart from `updated_at`) is changed, you should simply exit the function.

Answer (score 2):

Pay extra attention to the part of the documentation sample code that you referenced:

```
// We'll only update if the name has changed.
// This is crucial to prevent infinite loops.
if (data.name == previousData.name) return;
```

You'll need to figure out a way to detect when the update performed by your function triggers a subsequent update at the same location.

Comment: Same pinch :P ... just a few seconds before you :D

Answer (score 2):

In the onUpdate trigger, add or update a timestamp field to the document with the latest time (`admin.firestore.fieldValue.serverTimestamp()`). For this example, I will call the timestamp variable `time`.

The `onUpdate` function gives you a `before` and `after` document. If the `before.time == after.time`, then you know the user made a change. If the `before.time !== after.time`, you know the cloud function made a change.

```
if(snap.before.data().time !== snap.after.data().time){
   // The cloud function altered the document.
   // Return to prevent recursion!
   return;
}
```

When you update the document from the client, also update the `time` variable with the latest time. This way, the cloud function doesn't terminate before executing the desired code.

Answer (score 0):

when you're writing a function triggered by itself, but changing just that updated_at field, you can check if the previous updated_at field is within a certain range of the new updated_at field.

The following code sits within your cloud function

```
.onUpdate( async (change) => {

})
```

```
//exit if the last write happened within 5 seconds
if(change.after.data().updated_at - change.before.data().updated_at <= 5) {
    return;
}

        const date: Date = new Date();

        try {
            await db
                .collection("collection_name")
                .doc(change.after.id)
                .set({ updated_at: date }, { merge: true });
        } catch (e) {
            functions.logger.log("failed updating doc in collection_name: ", e);
            return false;
        }

return true;
```

I'm using 5 seconds because
-I don't care if my updated timestamp is off by 5 seconds
-I'm not sure in production how long latency could be (this condition works also with 1s, and the cloud function in the emulator ran about every ~0.015 s)

Comment: with all respect, there are a lot of circumstances where this pattern breaks down and i don't think it is a good example for others to follow