# How does one prevent Cloud Functions from recursively triggering themselves

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm in quite a predicament. I created a cloud function that would update the "updated_at" field in a user's profile, that is triggered every time the user updates some part of their profile. To my horror however, this update (completed via the cloud function), is continuously triggering the cloud function also. So I just had the function complete 1000's of updates in the last few minutes and my only solution appeared to be to delete the function on the server. So how does one go about updating this field if it triggers itself? Here's the function that caused the issue:

```
exports.generateUpdatedAtTest = functions.database.instance("bd-dev")
.ref("/UserData/{uid}/profile")
.onUpdate((snapshot, context) => {
  functions.logger.log("updated_at on ", context.params.uid);
  return snapshot.before.ref.update({"updated_at": new Date()});
});
```

Comment: Is this the only thing your Cloud Function is doing? If so, consider using Security Rules to mandate the inclusion of an `updated_at` value set to [`serverTimestamp()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.md#servertimestamp) for each update submitted by your clients. On the rules side, this would be done by comparing the new value against [`now`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#now).

Comment: Refer to this video [Realtime Database triggers (pt.2) with Cloud Functions for Firebase - Firecasts](https://youtu.be/Bdm7QNwSHOg?si=nonGxAxXDNmBbZu0&t=185) about how to terminate infinite loops in cloud functions triggers.

Comment: @RohitKharche That video definitely pointed me in the right direction. This response better helped me understand how to detect if the change is caused organically through the app or by the trigger itself https://stackoverflow.com/a/67731096/2793703

Answer (score 3):

There is no special flag or signal you can send to stop a function from taking an action that would invoke itself.  You must to devise a way to detect if your function should *do nothing* when invoked, using only the data available at the time of the invocation (especially the existing data in the database).  This strategy is going to vary from function to function.

For your specific case, one possibility is look at the current value of the `updated_at` field, and decide not to update it again if it's within some small threshold from the current time.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that adding this check helped prevent the recursion. Basically once the onUpdate trigger calls itself once more, the before and after updated_at fields would only be the same if the change was generated from the app. So this finally helped.

```
// updated_at should only be the same if profile updated in app
  if (before.updated_at !== after.updated_at) {
    console.log("Cancel onUpdate trigger.");
    return null;
  }
```